# What would be a good way to query a MongoDB database from a local client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to setup a MongoDB database, but I know that most prospective users will require a graphical front end to be able to use it at all. My idea was to build a local website stored on a computer which provides input fields for users to make queries to the database.

At first, this seemed easy enough. MongoDB is comfortable to use and learning how to make queries was rather simple. What I found difficult is integrating it with my front end website. I learned that MongoDB does not natively provide support for client-side JS and that I should rather use node.js to communicate with the database. Setting up a node.js server and sending data back and forth between node.js and MongoDB was equally simple. But for me this just shifted the problem to handling the communication between the client and the node.js server.

I tried to do this via Express, but as far as I understand this would mean encoding MongoDB queries into a route in the client-side JS, sending a http request to the node.js server, resolving the routes to obtain again the MongoDB queries, and finally sending the queries to the MongoDB server, receiving an answer and responding to the client. This seems like an overly complicated solution and involves a lot of programming to parse the strings.

Is there an easier way to communicate with a MongoDB database from client-side JS? How is this normally done?

Comment: No, there's not. The process you described is exactly what needs to be done to get this to work - that's how it's normally done.

Comment: Mongo Shell provides interactive JavaScript interface to the MongoDB database.You can setup [role based access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/index.html) (users and roles) - this allows controlled access to the collections in the database. You can also consider GUI tools like MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after the comments and responses indicated that this is really the "standard way" of doing things, I tried to send my queries through the node.js server as described in my question. Once I discovered `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` it turned out to be easier than I initially thought.

I now build my queries in the client-side JS, encode them via `JSON.stringify()` and send them to the node.js server like

```
var queryString = JSON.stringify(query);
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url  = 'http://localhost:8080/db?qs='+queryString;
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
```

Then, in the server-side JS the query is decoded and passed on to MongoDB:

```
app.get('/db', function(request, response) {
  var query = JSON.parse(request.query.qs);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var db = client.db("db");
    db.collection("coll").find(query).limit(100).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if(err) throw err;
      response.json(result);
      client.close();
    });
  });
});
```

For simple queries, this works just as desired. I guess it will be more difficult if I want to use operators in the queries, but for now this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing direct MongoDB from client side involve lot of security issues which is not good way to design a structure. 
using NodeJS app which includes REST api which you earlier defined is the good way to accessing MongoDB data as per i know. I think you should go with ExpressJs app and there REST apis.